# Clearing in_memory workspace within ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, in-memory

I have been using `in_memory` workspace within ArcGIS 10.1 ModelBuilder as part of a workflow to mosaic and clip raster datasets to study area bounds (Figure 1).  The model runs fine the first round but crashes the program on the second or third run.  I suspect two issues may be occuring: 1) Memory limitation are being exceeded or 2) There is conflict when trying to overwrite temp files `in_memory`.

**Is there a way to clear `in_memory` workspace from within ModelBuilder?**

Figure 1.

[image]

**Edit:**

The final model that is now stable

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the [Delete tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000052000000) and specify `%in_memory%` as the Input Data Element. I would also make `mosaic_clp.img` a [precondition](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_preconditions/002w0000007r000000/) for the Delete operation, to make sure the `in_memory` workspace isn't cleared prematurely.

Comment: Happy to help! Also, I haven't checked, but I think you can select `in_memory` from the Delete tool's dropdown menu -- it wouldn't change the way the model works at all, but it would remove the redundant `%in_memory%` variable bubble.

Comment: I followed your description, and it seems I cannot add %in_memory% as Input Data Element - it tells me there is no such element. However, if I use in_memory without the %, it works fine!